# Lab Activity; Track Laps To Miles

Tags: input, methods, return, output, calculation

this is one of the labs for my college class and with this one, I don't really know what to do. These are the instructions:
One lap around a standard high-school running track is exactly 0.25 miles. Define a method named lapsToMiles that takes a double as a parameter, representing the number of laps, and returns a double that represents the number of miles. Then, write a main program that takes a number of laps as an input, calls method lapsToMiles() to calculate the number of miles, and outputs the number of miles.

```
Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", yourValue);

Ex: If the input is:

7.6
the output is:

1.90
Ex: If the input is:

2.2
the output is:

0.55
The program must define and call a method:
public static double lapsToMiles(double userLaps)
```

This is what I have so far:
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class LabProgram {
   
   public static double lapsToMiles(double userLaps) {
      userLaps = userMiles/0.25;
      return double userLaps;
   
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      double userLaps = scnr.nextDouble();
      
      userLaps.lapsToMiles();
      
      System.out.printf("%.2f\n", lapsToMiles);
      
      
      
   }
}
```

I've been having trouble with it, I don't know if I set it up right.

Comment: I've been getting errors too. such as this one: LabProgram.java:7: error: '.class' expected
      return double userLaps;
                    ^
1 error

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static double lapsToMiles(double userLaps) {
    
      return (double) userLaps*0.25f;
   
}
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      double userLaps = scnr.nextDouble();
      
   
      
      System.out.printf("%.2f\n", lapsToMiles(userLaps));  
   
}
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?